How to extract derivation for each column from sql select query in python
Is there a way to extract derivation for each column of a sql query 
This is an Example Query
SELECT
    col1 AS c1,
    SUBSTR(
      CONCAT(
          CASE
              WHEN UPPER(RTRIM(M.col2)) IN('C', 'P') 
                  THEN 'P'
              WHEN M.col3 IS NULL 
                  THEN M.col4
              ELSE 
                  CASE
                      WHEN UPPER(RTRIM(M.col5)) IN('', 'D') 
                                OR M.col6 IS NULL 
                          THEN 'D'
                      WHEN UPPER(RTRIM(M.col7)) IN('C', 'P') 
                          THEN 'P'
                      ELSE CAST(NULL AS STRING)
                  END
          END, 
        ' '), 1, 1
    ) AS c2,
    SUBSTR(
        CONCAT(
            SUBSTR(CAST(col8 AS STRING), 1, 5), 
            '|', COALESCE(col9, 'NULL')
        ), 1, 100
    ) AS c3,
    SUBSTR(CONCAT('test', '   '), 1, 3) AS c4,
    SUBSTR('test', 1, 10) AS c5
    ...

output -
c1 - col1
c2 -
    SUBSTR(
        CONCAT(
            CASE
                WHEN UPPER(RTRIM(M.col2)) IN('C', 'P') 
                    THEN 'P'
                WHEN M.col3 IS NULL 
                    THEN M.col4
                ELSE 
                    CASE
                        WHEN UPPER(RTRIM(M.col5)) IN('', 'D')
                                OR M.col6 IS NULL 
                            THEN 'D'
                        WHEN UPPER(RTRIM(M.col7)) IN('C', 'P') 
                            THEN 'P'
                        ELSE CAST(NULL AS STRING)
                    END
            END, 
        ' '), 1, 1
    ) 

c3 -
    SUBSTR(
        CONCAT(
            SUBSTR(CAST(col8 AS STRING), 1, 5), 
                '|', 
            COALESCE(col9, 'NULL')
        ), 1, 100
    ) 

c4 - SUBSTR(CONCAT('test', '   '), 1, 3)
c5 - SUBSTR('test', 1, 10) AS
I tried using sql-parse library, but was able to just get the list of column used (c1, c2, c3 ...), need derivation for data lineage purpose.

Please upload sample input & expected  output ? @AnkitKotharkar
